# What's the statistical method where you add a certain number to each sample to make the distribution slightly more uniform?

Tags: probability, estimation

Please forgive my lack of knowledge - it's been a while since I've taken classes in statistics, and even then, it was not my strong point.  I'm trying to recall a method used to upweight all values in the distribution using a uniform distribution - it was called something like k+1?  Essentially, the method consisted of adding a specific value to all elements in the distribution, to emulate the effect of sampling with a uniform distribution for all elements, so that no element has a value of 0 or close to it.

---

Edit: I recently (it's currently October 2015) came across the term for this method: it's called adding pseudocounts (or Laplace estimators), at least in the context that I was referring to it. Just adding this in case anyone else can use that information.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated!. Please explain what 'normalize' means in this context - unfortunately it has several common meanings.

Comment: Can you give some more context, please? Avoiding the ambiguous word 'normalize' would also help (replace it with what that's supposed to actually achieve). Please be explicit about what is actually happening and what kind of task this is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're making reference to the effect of a prior distribution over the probability of success $\theta$ on a binomial outcome. For example, if we're thinking about flipping a coin, we might want to place a prior over $\theta=\Pr(\text{heads})$. A beta prior for a binomial likelihood has the benefit of conjugacy, and a $\text{B}(1,1)$ prior is uniform over its support. The result is that each of the "prior heads and tails" is added to the number of heads and tails we actually observed in the experiment: for $k$ heads and $n-k$ tails, the posterior distribution $\theta\sim\text{B}(k+1,n-k+1)$.

Comment: If you're right, that would be an applause-worthy deciphering of the question.

Comment: Thanks for answering - sorry for my lack of clarity. I believe that is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks, Glen! It's not often that I get to answer a question 'round these parts, but, like a stopped clock, I'm occasionally correct.

Comment: @abr If you've found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting or even accepting it (but only if you think that it fully and completely answers your question).

Comment: I did accept it - I think - but let me know if I didn't.  You did completely answer it, I think (I used this method in a bioinformatics class, so that wasn't the language we used, but it sounds like it has the same effect).

Comment: abr: you accepted it. That's what the tick indicates. If you are able to improve your question, you may end up with enough reputation to also upvote it (two upvotes would be enough; I'd certainly upvote a clearer question).

Comment: @abr Thank you! The "checkmark" must have just been slow on my end. Glad that I could help.

Comment: @Glen_b - I did try to improve it, but I'm not sure how much it helped.  I don't really remember much about the method and the context, so it has been a bit hard to explain it.

Comment: abr -- Explaining things like what you mean by 'upweight all the values' and the sense in which you're 'using a uniform distribution', for example, would be improvements. If you're unable to do so, then it can't be helped.